# symbol for proper ideal (\unlhd + \lneq)

Tags: symbols, overlays

How can I write the symbol

[image]

for a proper ideal?

The standard relations `\leq,\subseteq` both have a "proper" version `\lneq,\subsetneq`, but I was unable to find a "proper" version of either `\unlhd` or `\trianglelefteq`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do by superimposing the symbols:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\properideal}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\lneq$\cr\raise.22ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}}}

\begin{document}
$I\properideal A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that changes size in subscripts/superscripts; some artifacts may appear at low screen resolution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\properideal}{\mathrel{\text{$\m@th\proper@ideal$}}}
\newcommand{\proper@ideal}{%
  \ooalign{$\lneq$\cr\raise.22ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$I\properideal A_{\properideal_{\properideal}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? The $<$ bit of this symbol is bold when I put it into a document, which is less than ideal...

Comment: @user1729 Maybe a follow-up question with a minimal example is better.

Comment: I was contemplating asking a new question, but I thought I would ask briefly here first. What do you mean by "a minimal example"?

Comment: An example of a `.tex` document that exhibits the problem, including all necessary packages. Don't forget a link to this question.

Comment: I think I'll wait until I've got a printed out a copy of the document before asking the question - I'm starting to worry it is just my screen playing tricks on me! (Although, for the record, my "minimal example" is exactly what you have written, above.)

Comment: @egreg Where is `\mathchoice`/`\mathpalette`? :)

Comment: @yo' Exercise for the reader