# Notation for proper normal subgroup

Tags: symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

Is there any easy way to put not-equal sign to any binary operation symbol like `\triangleright` etc.

For example, I want to use it for a proper normal subgroup.

If found one solution for `\lhd` but it is not so simple ([symbol for proper ideal (\unlhd + \lneq)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/symbol-for-proper-ideal-unlhd-lneq))

Answer (score 4):

You may choose between the `amssymb`version and a variant borrowed from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nvartrianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{matha}{"9E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartrianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{matha}{"9C}

\begin{document}

    \[ H \nvartrianglelefteq G \qquad H \vartrianglelefteq G\]

    \[ H \ntrianglelefteq G \qquad H \trianglelefteq G \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The general easy way to do this is to use `\underset` from the `amsmath` package,

```
\underset{\neq}{\triangleleft}
```

however it will give you a rather bulky symbol, that you would not want to use in running text.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  H \triangleleft G \qquad
  H \underset{\neq}{\triangleleft} G
\end{equation*}
In text we say \( H \triangleleft G \) and \( H\ne G \).

\end{document}
```